# printing function suppressed in C++

Tags: c++, printing

I'm trying to design a matrix solving program in C++. When I call the function Ax_b() it's supposed to create an integer matrix out of strings and then print the output. This works when I call the function in the main, but when I have conditions on the function everything except the printing works.

Example:

```
void main(){

      Ax_b(); //runs fine and prints output to console

}
```

but...

```
void main(){


     int x;

     while(true){

         cout<<"What would you like to do?"<<endl<<endl;
         cout<<"1. Solve Ax=b"<<endl;
         cout<<"1. Reduce a matrix to REF"<<endl;
         cout<<"2. Reduce a matrix to RREF"<<endl;
         cout<<"3. Find the nullspace of a matrix"<<endl;
         cout<<"4. Quit"<<endl<<endl;

         cin>>x;

         cout<<endl;

         if(x == 1)
             Ax_b(); //runs function but doesn't print matrix to console
         else
             exit(1);


     }

 }
```

Ax_b() looks like this:

```
void Ax_b(){

     vector<string> strMatrix = storeStrings();
     vector<vector<int>> matrix = parseMatrix(strMatrix);

     printMatrix(matrix);

}
```

printMatrix:

```
void printMatrix(vector<vector<int>> matrix){

     int mSize = matrix.size();
     int vSize = matrix[0].size();

     for(int i = 0; i < mSize; i++){

         cout<<endl;

         for(int j = 0; j < vSize; j++){

             cout<<matrix[i][j]<<" ";

         }

      }

     cout<<endl<<endl;

}
```

It seems so stupid but I can't figure out why this isn't working, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Where is `printMatrix` code?

Comment: What is the size of matrix inside the printMatrix function call?

Comment: @FlorisVelleman it's variable. I've only tried with 2x2 and 3x3.

Comment: @Radix When you step through it with a debugger, does it hit the print statements inside the printMatrix function?

Comment: If you don't want to wait for the right answer you can easily insert some debug printings to rule out some scenarios, print the choice x before the `if-else` to check it is indeed `1`; print a title inside  `printMatrix` to check if it enters there at all. You'll be smarter after you see those results.

Comment: @ilomambo so I did what you suggested and it does enter the print function but for some reason it says the size of the vectors inside the matrix are 0...which would explain why it's not printing but not why the vectors seem to change size depending on how I call the function...

Comment: Just to be clear about your problem: if you call `Ax_b()` before the `if-else` it prints OK, but not when inside the `if-else`? This does not make sense, I would bet that if you add `Ax_b()` before the `if-else` it won't print either. From your comment above, I would also put some debug printings in `parseMatrix` to check how the matrix is constructed (or not constructed)

Comment: @ilomambo I added the Ax_b() call inside the while loop but outside the if/else and got no printing. However, when there's nothing else in the main and I call the function it prints to the console.

Comment: Although it is hard to tell why you see what you see, you grasp now how to debug your code, just do it step by step, confirming each step with some printing and going deeper into the code until you understand what is failing.

Comment: Maybe you can post your whole program including the storeString() and parseMatrix() Functions? I'd also call `Ax_b()` before the loop and check whether the matrix is printed then.

Answer (score 0):

We don't see at the point of posting this anwser the printMatrix function, possibly Your problem is there. remember that console is a stream, maybe You're missing a endl to force the flush.

Comment: have You checked if the matrix is created with gdb or equivalent debugger?

Comment: no, but I think I have the problem narrowed down. thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so...

1. Did you try printing something outside of the loops, but in the function?
2. Maybe if you did if (cond) with the {} something might change.
3. Look out for those loops! I once did a while (cond) with a ; before the {}. That was not fun. None of the code inside ran until I removed the ;.